# Outlook 2016 left tab icon missing from ruler

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

Every once and a while, Outlook 2016 (32-bit) losses the left tab hourglass on the ruler. (HTML format). I can get a tab stop by manually adding one, but how do I keep the hourglass always visible?

[image: Hourglass]

It does not seem to matter if I create a new email or reply to another email.

Thanks for the help